# /var/lib/snapd/snaps/*.snap: can't open blockdev errors keep coming back despite several tries to remove totally snap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, block-device, snap

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 on a I9 cpu + Nvidia Geforce RTX 2080 ti and the driver 545 right now. Everything works great,but not snap. I've tried to remove it as soon as I have installed Ubuntu from scratch,but something went wrong and now I see the following errors during boot :

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_607.snap: Can't open blockdev 
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_864.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_2517.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firmware-updater_109.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_141.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_87.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_1046.snap: Can't open blockdev
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_959.snap: Can't open blockdev 
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_18933.snap: Can't open blockdev 
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_20290.snap: Can't open blockdev 
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_83.snap: Can't open blockdev
```

Anyway,snap seems to work ok (because I've reinstalled it with the purpose to remove it again when I was able to fix the errors) :

```
# snap list

Name         Version    Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes

core         16-2.60.4  16202  latest/stable  canonical✓  core 
hello-world  6.4        29     latest/stable  canonical✓  -
```

What I want to do really is to remove snap totally,including the errors that you see above. I tried different approaches,but none worked,errors keep coming back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `snapd` and orphaned packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

Prevent from updating:

```
sudo apt-mark hold snapd
```

You can also manually delete these folders:

```
rm -rf ~/snap
sudo rm -rf /snap
sudo rm -rf /var/snap
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/snapd
```

Comment: On " / " I have a directory called "snap" with these files inside : bare ; core22 ; gnome-42-2204 ; snap-store ; bin ; firefox ; gtk-common-themes  snapd ; core  firmware-updater; hello-world ; snapd-desktop-integration. If I try to remove them,Ubuntu 23.10 tells that they are missing.

Comment: @Marietto How are you trying to delete them? Can you share the error message or a screeenshot?